# How to set nullable foreign reference in asp.net mvc code first method?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc

In my project there is one to may relationship with two table(questions and asnwars). but when creating question no need to add answar but in my problem getting this error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

how can I solve this? is there any wrong thing in my code

this is the code what I tried.

```
    public class QuestionDTO
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string question { get; set; }
        public int votes { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser starter { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<VegCategoryDTO> tags { get; set; }
        public ICollection<AnswerDTO> answers { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
         modelBuilder.Entity<QuestionDTO>().ToTable("tblQuestion");
         modelBuilder.Entity<AnswerDTO>()
            .HasRequired<QuestionDTO>(s => s.Question)
            .WithMany(g => g.answers)
            .HasForeignKey<int>(s => s.QuestionId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();
       }
    }
```

```
    public class QuestionController : ApiController
    {
    [AllowAnonymous]
        public QuestionVM Post(QuestionVM model)
        {
            //if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            //{
            //    return null;
            //}
            QuestionDTO dto = new QuestionDTO();
            using (Db db = new Db())
            {
                dto.Id = model.Id;
                dto.Title = model.Title;
                dto.votes = model.votes;
                dto.question = model.question;
                ApplicationUser currentUser = (new ApplicationDbContext()).Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == userId);

                dto.starter = currentUser;
                dto.tags = model.tags;
                dto.answers = model.answers;

                db.Questions.Add(dto);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            //_DbContext.SaveChanges();
            return new QuestionVM(dto);
        }
    }
```

```
    public class Db : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<VegCategoryDTO> VegCategories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<QuestionDTO> Questions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AnswerDTO> Answers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<QuestionDTO>()
                .HasMany<VegCategoryDTO>(s => s.tags)
                .WithMany(c => c.Questions)
                .Map(cs =>
                {
                    cs.MapLeftKey("QuestiontRefId");
                    cs.MapRightKey("VegCategoryRefId");
                    cs.ToTable("QuestiontVegCategory");
                });
            modelBuilder.Entity<AnswerDTO>()
            .HasRequired<QuestionDTO>(s => s.Question)
            .WithMany(g => g.answers)
            .HasForeignKey<int>(s => s.QuestionId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you debugged to identify from which line your are getting `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`?

Comment: @TanvirArjel yes it will return db.Questions.Add(dto); line in questionController

Comment: Have you any other dbcontext except `ApplicationDbContext`?

Comment: @TanvirArjel yes my project has two DbContext

Comment: Add this dbCotnext  to the question including all code of this dbContext.

Comment: but other controller and didn't return like this error. they are working properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186556/discussion-between-tanvirarjel-and-kgdc).

Comment: @TanvirArjel this is the other DBcontext

Comment: Check the chat!